# How to send mail multiple Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I send to 1 account but it send 2 times in 1 account I want to send multiple mail

Laravel

```
public function get_sendmail(Request $request) {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'subject' => 'min:2',
            'message' => 'min:10']);

        $recipients = [ ["email" => "$request->email"], ["email" => "$request->email"] ];

        $data = array(
            'subject' => $request->subject,
            'bodyMessage' => $request->message
        );

        foreach($recipients as $recipient) {
            // here you declare variables accesable in view file
            $dataToPassToEmailView = [];
            // **key** of this table is variable **name in view**
            $dataToPassToEmailView['recipient'] = $recipient;

            Mail::send('email.contact', $dataToPassToEmailView, function($message) use ($recipient, $data) {
                $message->to($recipient['email']);
                $message->subject($data['subject']);

            });
        }

            return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'success!');

        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$recipients` have the same address saved two times, cause you are adding the same `$request->email` to both of `recipients` email key.

```php
 $recipients = [ 
                   [
                      "email" => "$request->email"
                   ],
                   [
                      "email" => "$request->email"
                   ] 
              ];
```

To solve this, you can send the `$request->email` as an array. If the request comes from a form, try something like this:

```html
<form action="{{ route('your-sendmail-route') }} method="YOUR METHOD">
    @csrf
    <label>First email:</label>
    <input name="email[]" type="email" class="email">
    <label>Second email:</label>
    <input name="email[]" type="email" class="email">
    <label>Third email:</label>
    <input name="email[]" type="email" class="email">
    <button type="submit">Send mail</button>
</form>
```

When you submit this form, in your controller you receive an array of emails, and then, can iterate through it:

```php
foreach($request->email as $email) {
    // here you declare variables accesable in view file
     $dataToPassToEmailView = [];
    // **key** of this table is variable **name in view**
     $dataToPassToEmailView['recipient'] = $email;
     Mail::send('email.contact', $dataToPassToEmailView, function($message) use 
         ($recipient, $data) {
             $message->to($email);
                 $message->subject($data['subject']);
            });
     }
```

I think it should solve your problem.